# Inconsistent results from equivalent integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Why is *Mathematica* returning different values for these two integrals:

[image: Complex Integral Sine Cosine]

I am just being introduced to complex integration, so it's possible that I have a misunderstanding of how this works, but in this case the functions inside the integral are completely equivalent.

For some reason the image is not displaying, here is the code:

```
Integrate[1/(a^2*Cos[t]^2 + b^2*Sin[t]^2), {t, 0, 2*Pi}]

Integrate[1/(a^2*((E^(I*t) + E^((-I)*t))/2)^2 + b^2*((E^(I*t) - E^((-I)*t))/(2*I))^2),
  {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Comment: What's interesting is, if you replace `a` and `b` with real numbers you get the correct answer instantly. So *Mathematica* knows how to do the integration either way, something is just off here.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a long comment:

One issue with the symbolic definite integral is that if `a` can be `b` complex, then you have to worry about the residues.

If we make the substitution in the integrand $z = e^{it}$ we get

```
fz = 1/(a^2 Cos[t]^2 + b^2 Sin[t]^2) /. {Cos[t] -> (z + 1/z)/2, Sin[t] -> (z - 1/z)/(2 I)} // Factor
```

> ```
> -(4 z^2) / ((-a - b - a z^2 + b z^2) (a - b + a z^2 + b z^2))
> ```

There are four poles of this function of `z`:

```
poles = z /. Solve[(-a - b - a z^2 + b z^2) (a - b + a z^2 + b z^2) == 0, z]
```

> ```
> {-(Sqrt[-a - b]/Sqrt[a - b]), Sqrt[-a - b]/Sqrt[a - b],
>  -(Sqrt[-a + b]/Sqrt[a + b]), Sqrt[-a + b]/Sqrt[a + b]}
> ```

The corresponding poles of the integrand are at (since $z = e^{it}$)

```
trigpoles = Log[poles]/I
```

> ```
> {-I Log[-(Sqrt[-a - b]/Sqrt[a - b])], -I Log[Sqrt[-a - b]/Sqrt[a - b]],
>  -I Log[-(Sqrt[-a + b]/Sqrt[a + b])], -I Log[Sqrt[-a + b]/Sqrt[a + b]]}
> ```

plus multiples of $2\pi$.  The residues at the poles are

```
res = SeriesCoefficient[-(1/(a^2 Cos[t]^2 + b^2 Sin[t]^2)), {t, #, -1}] & /@ trigpoles
```

> ```
> {-(I/(2 a b)), -(I/(2 a b)), I/(2 a b), I/(2 a b)}
> ```

**If** *Mathematica* is using residues to compute the complex exponential integral,
then it has to decide which residues to use, which depends which the poles lie inside the contour of integration.  (In this integral, it will be either the first two or the last two.)

I suspect *Mathematica* has trouble deciding.  Perhaps it picks all four.  Their total is zero, which agrees with the output.

**Example**

For what it's worth, here's an example of how to compute this integral via the Residue Theorem.  I'll work with the integrand `fz` expressed in terms of $z = e^{it}$ (above).  Thus our contour will be the unit circle.  Since $dt = i\,z\;dz$, the corresponding complex integrand with respect to $dz$ will be `fz/(I z)`.  One can check the residues are the same:

```
res = SeriesCoefficient[fz/(I z), {z, #, -1}] & /@ poles
```

> ```
> {I/(2 a b), I/(2 a b), -(I/(2 a b)), -(I/(2 a b))}
> ```

Let's pick an explicit `a` and `b`:

```
abexample = {a -> 1 + I, b -> 2 - I};
```

The poles are

```
Norm /@ N[poles /. abexample]
```

> ```
> {1.15829, 1.15829, 0.86334, 0.86334}
> ```

Now we pick out the residues inside the unit circle and multiply their total by `2 π I`:

```
2 π I Pick[res /. abexample, poles /. abexample, _?(Norm[#] < 1 &)] // Total
```

> ```
> (3/5 - I/5) \[Pi]
> ```

Compare with the output of the first (trig) integral:

```
(2 Sqrt[b^2/a^2] \[Pi])/b^2 /. abexample
```

> ```
> (3/5 - I/5) \[Pi]
> ```

Or with the definite integral:

```
Integrate[1/(a^2*Cos[t]^2 + b^2*Sin[t]^2) /. abexample, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

> ```
> (3/5 - I/5) \[Pi]
> ```

Comment: Does Mathematica therefore assume, during the first integration with the trig functions, that $a$ and $b$ are not complex?

Comment: @MichaelBoratko No, I'm pretty sure it treats `a` and `b` as complex.  It must set the integral up (internally) in a way that leads to the right answer.  IMO, Daniel Lichtblau's comment on another answer deserves consideration.  He knows more about how `Integrate` works than I do.

Answer (score 2):

Just an observation.
I think something goes wrong already here :

```
Integrate[1/(a^2 Cos[t]^2 + b^2 Sin[t]^2), t]
(* ArcTan[(b Tan[t])/a]/(a b) *)

Integrate[TrigToExp[1/(a^2 Cos[t]^2 + b^2 Sin[t]^2)], t]
(* -((I ArcTanh[(-a^2 - b^2 - a^2 E^(2 I t) + b^2 E^(2 I t))/(2 a b)])/(a b)) *)
```

Comment: That second antiderivative is not incorrect. While I have not yet checked, my guess is it has a path singularity, possibly parametrized in `(a,b)`, that Integrate fails to locate.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for expressing this more precisely.